# typo3: issue with locallang xml

Tags: typo3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3locallang>
    <meta type="array">
        <type>database</type>
        <description>Language labels for extension 'dagou_user'</description>
    </meta>
    <data type="array">
        <languageKey index="default" type="array">
            <!-- Email -->
            <label index="email_notify_employer_body"><![CDATA[A new Employer has signed up!<br /><br />Account Name: ###USERNAME###<br />Email: ###EMAIL###<br />Full Name: ###NAME###<br />Company Name: ###COMPANY###<br />Location: ###CITY### ###STATE###, ###ZIP###]]></label>
            <label index="email_notify_employer_subject">New Employer</label>
        ...
        </languageKey>
    </data>
</T3locallang>
```

Above code is taken from `locallang_dagouuser.xml`, meanwhile I am reading this document: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.1.0/view/7/2/

Questions:

1. For `type="array"`, is there any other value I can assign for `type`? such as `type="string"`...
2. `<type>database</type>`, in the document, it is said `"database" : Used for labels of database tables and fields.`, what does this mean? how could I use these labels with DB tables and fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, there is just this one type.
2. This is just a hint for the reader what the purpose of this language file is. When you take at look at the `TCA` of the extension, you will see something like

> 'label' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:sys_language_uid_formlabel'

This is one of the places those language labels for database fields are used.